# What's the advantage of majorization-minimization (MM) algorithm

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

The [majorization-minimization (MM) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM_algorithm) is a framework for convex and nonconvex optimization. When applied to nonconvex optimization, the MM algorithm solves a sequence of convex problems to obtain a [KKT point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) of the original nonconvex problem. As we know, both MM and gradient descent converge to a KKT point but MM is slower than gradient descent.

So what's the advantage of MM algorithm compared with gradient descent?

Comment: If the function being optimized contains a long, narrow valley, then gradient descent gets stuck taking a large number of zig-zag steps down that valey and converges very slowly - see Numerical Recipes page 516 of third edition, and other references cited there.  MM is slower in most situations but fares better against this nemesis of gradient descent.